# How to use regularization with Dynamic_rnn

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, regularized

I want to use l2-regularizatin with Dynamic_rnn in tensorflow but it seems this is not handled gracefully currently. While loop is the source of error. Below is a sample code snippet to reproduce the problem

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
tf.reset_default_graph()
batch = 2
dim = 3
hidden = 4

with tf.variable_scope('test', regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(0.001)):
    lengths = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[batch])
    inputs = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[batch, None, dim])
    cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(hidden)
    cell_state = cell.zero_state(batch, tf.float32)
    output, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, inputs, lengths, initial_state=cell_state)
    inputs_ = np.asarray([[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]],
                        [[6, 6, 6], [7, 7, 7], [8, 8, 8], [9, 9, 9]]],
                        dtype=np.int32)
    lengths_ = np.asarray([3, 1], dtype=np.int32)
this_throws_error = tf.losses.get_regularization_loss()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    output_ = sess.run(output, {inputs: inputs_, lengths: lengths_})
    print(output_)

INFO:tensorflow:Cannot use 'test/rnn/gru_cell/gates/kernel/Regularizer/l2_regularizer' as input to 'total_regularization_loss' because 'test/rnn/gru_cell/gates/kernel/Regularizer/l2_regularizer' is in a while loop.

total_regularization_loss while context: None
test/rnn/gru_cell/gates/kernel/Regularizer/l2_regularizer while context: test/rnn/while/while_context
```

How can i add l2 regularization if i have dynamic_rnn in my network? Currently i can be going ahead with getting trainable collection at the loss calculation and adding l2 loss there but i also have word vectors as trainable parameters which i dont want to regularize on

Comment: Did you fond a solution to this by any chance?

Comment: @w4nderlust - No. I collect the variables and add the l2 loss manually for l2 regularization

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue, and I've been trying to solve it with `tensorflow==1.9.0`.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
tf.reset_default_graph()
batch = 2
dim = 3
hidden = 4

with tf.variable_scope('test', regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(0.001)):
    lengths = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[batch])
    inputs = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[batch, None, dim])
    cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(hidden)
    cell_state = cell.zero_state(batch, tf.float32)
    output, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, inputs, lengths, initial_state=cell_state)
inputs_ = np.asarray([[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]],
                        [[6, 6, 6], [7, 7, 7], [8, 8, 8], [9, 9, 9]]],
                        dtype=np.int32)
lengths_ = np.asarray([3, 1], dtype=np.int32)
this_throws_error = tf.losses.get_regularization_loss()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    output_ = sess.run(output, {inputs: inputs_, lengths: lengths_})
    print(output_)
    print(sess.run(this_throws_error))
```

This is the result of running the code:

```
...
File "/Users/piero/Development/mlenv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_util.py", line 314, in CheckInputFromValidContext
    raise ValueError(error_msg + " See info log for more details.")
ValueError: Cannot use 'test/rnn/gru_cell/gates/kernel/Regularizer/l2_regularizer' as input to 'total_regularization_loss' because 'test/rnn/gru_cell/gates/kernel/Regularizer/l2_regularizer' is in a while loop. See info log for more details.
```

Then I tried to put the `dynamic_rnn` call outside of the variable scope:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
tf.reset_default_graph()
batch = 2
dim = 3
hidden = 4

with tf.variable_scope('test', regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(0.001)):
    lengths = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[batch])
    inputs = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[batch, None, dim])
    cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(hidden)
    cell_state = cell.zero_state(batch, tf.float32)
output, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, inputs, lengths, initial_state=cell_state)
inputs_ = np.asarray([[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]],
                        [[6, 6, 6], [7, 7, 7], [8, 8, 8], [9, 9, 9]]],
                        dtype=np.int32)
lengths_ = np.asarray([3, 1], dtype=np.int32)
this_throws_error = tf.losses.get_regularization_loss()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    output_ = sess.run(output, {inputs: inputs_, lengths: lengths_})
    print(output_)
    print(sess.run(this_throws_error))
```

In theory this should be fine, as the regularization applies to the weights of the rnn that should contain variables initialized when the rnn cells are created.

This is the output:

```
[[[ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 0.1526176   0.33048663 -0.02288104 -0.1016309 ]
  [ 0.24402776  0.68280864 -0.04888818 -0.26671126]
  [ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]]

 [[ 0.01998052  0.82368904 -0.00891946 -0.38874635]
  [ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]]]
0.0
```

So placing the `dynami_rnn` call outside the variable scope works, in the sense that does not return errors, but the value of the loss is 0, suggesting that it's actually not really considering any weight from the rnn to compute the l2 loss.

Then I tried with `tensorflow==1.12.0`.
This is the output for the first script with `dynamic_rnn` inside the scope:

```
[[[ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
  [-0.17653276  0.06490126  0.02065791 -0.05175343]
  [-0.413078    0.14486027  0.03922977 -0.1465032 ]
  [ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]]

 [[-0.5176822   0.03947531  0.00206934 -0.5542746 ]
  [ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]]]
0.010403235
```

And this is the output with `dynamic_rnn` outside the scope:

```
[[[ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 0.04208181  0.03031874 -0.1749279   0.04617848]
  [ 0.12169671  0.09322995 -0.29029205  0.08247502]
  [ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]]

 [[ 0.09673716  0.13300316 -0.02427006  0.00156245]
  [ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]]]
0.0
```

The fact that the version with dynamic_rnn inside the scope returns a non-zero value suggests that it is working correctly, while in the other case, the returned value 0 suggests that it is not behaving as expected.
So the bottom line is: this was a bug in `tensorflow` that they solved between version `1.9.0` and version `1.12.0`.